# \multicolumn alternative in KaTeX

Tags: alignment, katex

I want to be able to align a single cell's contents differently from the rest. I've found that this can be done using \multicolumn in LaTeX however, I have yet to find an alternative that works in KaTeX. Below is roughly what my current table looks like. Say that I want to align the cell with "Hello" to the right, how would I go about that in KaTeX?

```
\begin{array}{|l|}
    \hline
    \text{Hi} \\
    \hline
    \text{Good Morning} \\
    \hline
    \text{Hello} \\
    \hline
    \text{Howdy} \\
    \hline
\end{array}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed in KaTeX you can't do *all* that you can do in LaTeX, even using a `tabular` environment is not trivial.

As long as your array or table must only conain text, I would rely on html `<table>` tag and CSS style:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Array?</title>
<style>
table,td{border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse}
td.cellle,td.cellri{padding:5px}
td.cellri{text-align:right}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td class="cellle">Hi</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cellle">Good Morning</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cellri">Hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cellle">Howdy</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
table,td{border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse}
td.cellle,td.cellri{padding:5px}
td.cellri{text-align:right}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td class="cellle">Hi</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cellle">Good Morning</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cellri">Hello</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cellle">Howdy</td></tr>
</table>
```

Also, if it is needed, you can then use the KaTeX inline math delimiters within any single cell, whose alignment you control by the CSS.

Comment: @FlintStone no problem! Comment if you need :)